# Trying to add a png shadow over an image, but menu is overlapping it oddly

Tags: html, css

I want there to be a shadow under the menu, but on top of the header. The problem is when hovering over the menu items, the shadow is showing through it. The orange part should just be solid and over the shadow.

http://jsfiddle.net/WjcvH/2/

Now, I can't add a z-index to the menu because I would have to add a position to it, and if I do that the drop down menus break in IE. Since my drop down menu is absolutely positioned, I found no possible way around this other than removing the position/zindex from #menu.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper-header">
<header id="header" class="sk-container">           
    <nav id="menu" class="sixteen columns">
        <ul id="nav">
        <li class="current first"><a href="#">Home</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">drop 1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">drop 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">drop 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">drop 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>   
    </ul>        
    </nav>        
    <!-- End nav#menu -->

    <!-- start header image -->
    <div id="header-image-container" class="sixteen columns">
        <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6233413/pcontrol/menu-shadow.png" style="position: absolute; width: 98%;">
        <img id="siteMainDynHeaderImage1" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6233413/pcontrol/header_image_1.jpg" >
    </div> 
    <!-- end header image -->

</header><!-- end header container -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is apply a z-index value, higher then the header on `ul#nav li ul`

Like this:

```
ul#nav li ul {
   z-index: 999;
}
```

Your menu is already set to `position: absolute`, so applying a z-index will work in this case.

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/WjcvH/3/

Comment: What version of IE?  I'm assuming IE8 and below.

Comment: No problem.  You had me wondering because I tested it in IE and it was working.  Good to know :)

Comment: Would you also happen to know why you can't hover over the 3rd level drop down?

Comment: You're altering a margin on a hover state for the menu `<ul>`, which is generally not a good idea.  Try removing: `ul#nav li ul:hover {margin-top: 0;}` and seeing if it fixes the issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30274/discussion-between-talena6-and-axel)